# Test what screen the mouse pointer is on

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am a JS/Node dev, and I have zero C# experience. I figured it would be pretty simple to write an exe I can run from node to take a screenshot. The problem is I am only interested in the screen that the mouse cursor is currently on. I found the following code to take the screenshot, but it only handles the main screen.

```
Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("asdf " + bounds.ToString());

using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }
    bitmap.Save("test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Is there a way to detect what screen the mouse cursor is on and take the screenshot?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The Screen object should be what you need.  Check out the AllScreens property.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Screen_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Right but how do I tell what screen the mouse is on? Do I need to loop through each screen and test against the mouse location? If so do I need to check each axis individually or is there a more convenient way of comparing locations?

Comment: Most UI things with Windows should have a Bounds or Rectangle object associated with it, which includes the coordinate data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp :P It turns out to be as simple as changing the point in `GetBounds` to the mouse location and the `CopyFromScreen` to start at the correct location:

```
Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Cursor.Position);
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(bounds.Location, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }
    bitmap.Save("cap.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: Way more compact than my answer. This is definitely the way to go. Glad it worked out for you

Answer (score 1):

Here I got the global mouse-position, and made it to a rectangle.

Then I checked every screens bounds if the mouse-position intersected with it.

From there I had the active screen so I just had to take a screenshot.
Hope this helps you.

```
private void takeScreenshot()
    {
        Bitmap screenshot;
        Graphics graphics;

        Rectangle mousePoint = new Rectangle(Cursor.Position, new Size(1, 1));

        Screen activeScreen = null;

        foreach (Screen s in Screen.AllScreens)
        {
            if (s.Bounds.IntersectsWith(mousePoint))
                activeScreen = s;
        }

        if (activeScreen == null)
            return;
        screenshot = new Bitmap(activeScreen.Bounds.Width, activeScreen.Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);

        graphics.CopyFromScreen(
            activeScreen.Bounds.X,
            activeScreen.Bounds.Y,
            0,
            0,
            activeScreen.Bounds.Size,
            CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

        screenshot.Save(@"C:\Users\David\Desktop\screen.png");
    }
```